# Why "fread: EFAULT, bad address" in this C function?

Tags: c, unix

The following function reads arbitrary data from the `stdin` and produces an `unsigned int` one a time.  If it finds `EOF`, it quits.  If the file is infinite (such as `/dev/urandom`), it goes on forever.  I have a file of about 95 MiB that makes it produce `fread: Bad address`.  Can you see why?

```
unsigned int generator(void)
{
  static unsigned int buffer[8192 / sizeof(unsigned int)];
  static unsigned int pos; /* where is our number? */
  static unsigned int limit; /* where does the data in the buffer end? */

  if (pos >= limit) {
    /* refill the buffer and continue by restarting at 0 */
    limit = fread(buffer, sizeof (unsigned int), sizeof buffer, stdin);

    if (limit == 0) {
      /* We read 0 bytes.  This either means we found EOF or we have
      an error.  A decent generator is infinite, so this should never
      happen. */
      if (ferror(stdin) != 0) {
        perror("fread"); exit(-1);
      }
      if (feof(stdin) != 0) {
        printf("generator produced eof\n");
        exit(0);
      }
    }

    pos = 0;

  }

  unsigned int random = buffer[pos]; /* get one */
  pos = pos + 1;
  return random;
}
```

Comment: Read up on what the third argument to `fread()` is supposed to be.

Comment: You nailed it.  It's the size.  I changed it to `(sizeof buffer) / sizeof(unsigned int)` and the problem is gone.  Thank you so much the answer!